# Log values insertion in database using syslog function

Tags: c, database, linux, rsyslog

How can we insert our log data using syslog function(rsyslogd) available in ubuntu linux to mysql/postgresql database table in c language. If anyone knows about good source of info about this then please let me know.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should have a look [to this](http://www.rsyslog.com/doc/rsyslog_mysql.html) which describe  how to output logs to a MySql database via the standard syslog mechanism.

Comment: édric I have read that link but this is not sufficient fully for making own schema, tables and templates to store in them. Any other good source will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Sushant:  You can create your own schema and customize the SQL template used.  Check out: http://www.rsyslog.com/doc/ommysql.html.